# LEFT JOIN null values concept

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have 'products' and 'product_translations' tables.
'product_translations' table has:
id, product_id, locale, name fields.

Now I want to select products and translations like that:

```
SELECT * FROM products AS P
LEFT JOIN product_trs Ptr on P.id = Ptr.product_id
WHERE locale = 'fr'
```

but the problem is that if product has no translations (yet) these products are not returned.

For example let's say my product_translations hat these rows:

```
id  pr_id locale    name
------------------------------
1    1    'en'    'product 1'
2    1    'fr'    'produit 1'
3    2    'en'    'product 2'
```

Now if I select with

```
WHERE locale = 'en'
```

I'll get 2 rows, If I run query with:

```
WHERE locale = 'fr'
```

I'll get one row

I want to get always 2 rows. Even If I have no translation. How can I do that?

Comment: Incomplete -- Which table is `locale` in?

Comment: @RickJames in product_trs (product translations)

Comment: So, it is not really a `LEFT` join?

Comment: @RickJames, Why?

Comment: `LEFT` implies that there might be a row in the "right" table.  `WHERE locale = 'fr'` says that there must be a row (and it shall have that value).  It takes me (for example) to analyze the query.  (By no means are you the only one who uses `LEFT` spuriously.)  Gordon's answer correctly uses `LEFT`.  This is a simple example of where `ON` and `WHERE` act differently.  (In many situations it does not matter which of those place you put a condition.)

Comment: @RickJames, you mean that I'm using incorrect LEFT with WHERE. The correct way (for my particular query) is using LEFT with ON and AND. Right?

Comment: (See Gordon's answer.)  Here's how I like to think about it:  `ON` is for saying how the tables are related; `WHERE` is used to exclude rows from the output.  Elaborating...  `LEFT JOIN` will succeed (with `NULLs`) even when the `ON` is false.  But if the `WHERE` is false, you won't even get a row of `NULLs`.

Comment: Yes, Gordons answer works for me. I just wanted to be sure what are you telling me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the condition in the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM products P LEFT JOIN
     product_trs Ptr 
     ON P.id = Ptr.product_id AND ptr.locale = 'fr';
```

Otherwise, the filtering happens *after* the `left join` -- and the `locale` is then `NULL` which fails the comparison.

The general rule is that filters on the first table in a `left join` go in the `where` clause.  Filters on the second (and subsequent) tables go in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

when you write your filter in "where" the records remove from result but if you put it in "join condition" the records just filter from the table not from result and returns null.
so the answer of Gordon is correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM products P LEFT JOIN
 product_trs Ptr 
 ON P.id = Ptr.product_id AND ptr.locale = 'fr';
```